# How to make visible and hide particular divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All div are generated dynamically, and having same class `class="bucket"`. This div had one more div inside `class="restPart"` rest part, which will hide, when page load first time.

What I want, I have more than one div,
1. Each divs **hides the rest part**, when page load **first time**.
2. Each div are diving into two part, one part will **always show** and **rest part will not show**.
3. Rest part will appear only when we click the link "**show more**",
4. When div are fully shown It will show link "**show less**", when we click on it, will hide the rest part.
5. This should work only for **one div on which we are clicking**, other divs should be unaware.

**_data_grid.html**

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $("#restPart").hide();
    $('#grid_content').on('click','.more', function(){
        //$("#restPart").show();
         $("div").children("div").show();
         $("#showRest").hide();

    });
    $('#grid_content').on('click','.less', function(){
        //$("#restPart").hide();
        $("#showRest").show();
         $(this).closest("div").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

```css
#grid_content {
    overflow: hidden; clear: both;
  }
  #grid_content .bucket {
    width: 290px; float: left; margin: 0 0 48px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #262626;
     background: $gray-lighter;

  }



  #grid_content .bucket ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  }

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="grid_content">
    <!--1st -->
    <div class="bucket">

        ... Content of visible part of bucket...                
        <a href="#" class="more" id="showRest">Show More.</a>
            <!--Below is the rest part when we click on the above link, Showrest it will show-->
        <div class="restPart" id="restPart">
            ... Content of Rest Part and click on the Show Less It will hide this div...
            <a href="#" class="less" id="showless">Show Less.</a> 
        </div> 

    </div>


    <!--2nd -->
    <div class="bucket">

        ... Content of visible part of bucket...                
        <a href="#" class="more" id="showRest">Show More.</a>

        <!--Below is the rest part when we click on the above link, Showrest it will show-->
        <div class="restPart" id="restPart">

            ... Content of Rest Part and click on the Show Less It will hide this div...

            <a href="#" class="less" id="showless">Show Less.</a> 
        </div> 

    </div>
</section>
```

**What  I want**

In the like following figures, more div will be generated **dynamically**, previously all will hide, when I click on **first div** show the rest content, but rest will not show, please see the **figure 2**,

[image]
**Figure 1**

[image]
**Figure 2**

Comment: @Cristik, thanks for response, I didn't get you, I think I tell the whole senario ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by others, remove duplicate IDs.

Judging by your image,
your button `Show more`, (once clicked - reveals the content and) becomes: `Show less` so...

- change button text (**So use a single toggle button!**)
- toggle/slide the previous DIV

```js
$(function() { // DOM is now ready

    $("#grid_content").on("click", ".toggle", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();    // Prevent window following #hash / jump
      var more = $(this).text() === "Show More";
      $(this).text(more ? "Show Less" : "Show More").prev(".restPart").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

```css
.bucket {
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 48px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #262626;
  background: lightgray;

}
.restPart{
  overflow:auto;
  display:none; /* hide initially */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="grid_content">

  <div class="bucket">
    <p>Visible part....</p>
    <div class="restPart">
      <p>Content...</p>
    </div> 
    <a href="#" class="toggle">Show More</a> 
  </div>

  <div class="bucket">
    <p>Visible part....</p>
    <div class="restPart">
      <p>Content...</p>
    </div> 
    <a href="#" class="toggle">Show More</a> 
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: thanks your code is same I want, your coding is working in http://jsfiddle.net/neelabhsingh/xr8getb7/, but same not working on my system..

Comment: @neelabhsingh that's probably cause you need to wrap jQuery into a DOM ready function `$(function(){ /*code here*/ });`

Comment: @neelabhsingh in the future, when you see answers that do not provide a DOM ready function, and you use your `<script>` at the top of your page (you should put usually JS before the closing `</body>` tag!!) that means that you should do that :)

Comment: @neelabhsingh also, make sure your text is exactly "Show More". if it's not you logically have to modify that inside the JS aswell.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan, your code is working, but same code is not working in my system..

Comment: @https://ideone.com/3NQrlC   please check this link,  Which have same code on my local machine   https://ideone.com/3NQrlC

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan  Please see this link https://ideone.com/3NQrlC  which has same code on my system..

Comment: Using text compare is not best practice in detecting action - I18N and stuff. For this kind of approach I suggest using some `$.data('opened', true|false)` attribute or similar

Comment: @KalleVolkov what you're suggesting does not solve i18n. languages would be solved by using 1: two buttons with pre-inserted language words (where one is hidden). 2. by using data attribute but like: `data-text="See Less"`. The `data` stuff do not solve that issue. Also your example can be done by simply: `var io = this.io ^= 1;` and you have a toggler that stores the state in the element's object `io` custom property. But yes, for multiple languages app/website you'll need a different  approach. Seems that languages are not an issue here...

Comment: @NeelabhSingh I've seen your code. You should revise my answer. All you need is there. (you forgot to add the DOM ready fn...)

Answer (score 2):

**First of all** - your naming strategy is a bit wrong. HTML document can contain (by standards) only one object with one ID - that's the purpose of ID as such. So, you can't have many objects with `id="showRest"` or `id="restPart"` or `id="showless"`.

**Possible solution** for your problem.

Design your HTML something like

```
<div class="bucket">
  <div class="mininfo">
    <div class="intro">some intro bucket 1...</div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="showmore">Show more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="maxinfo" style="display: none;">
    <div class="intro">Here is full content 1 of everything</div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="showless">Show less</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bucket">
  <div class="mininfo">
    <div class="intro">some intro bucket 2...</div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="showmore">Show more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="maxinfo" style="display: none;">
    <div class="intro">Here is full content 2 of everything</div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="showless">Show less</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next, in JavaScript part you can use selectors such as:

```
$(".bucket .showmore").on('click', function(){
  var $bucket = $(this).parents('.bucket');
  $bucket.find('.mininfo').hide();
  $bucket.find('.maxinfo').show();
});
$(".bucket .showless").on('click', function(){
  var $bucket = $(this).parents('.bucket');
  $bucket.find('.mininfo').show();
  $bucket.find('.maxinfo').hide();
});
```

**Updated 1:** added two buckets to example.

**Updated 2:** [example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgt39a2s/)

**Updated 3:** [update in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgt39a2s/1/) with some content kept

Comment: your jQ can even be simplified to a single function. Also AFAICS your events are one-way-only

Comment: Of course it can be reduced even to single line :) This way (I think/hope) it's more readable to OP.

Comment: @Kalle Volkov, thanks for response, Yaa, I know, But how you hundle the above condition, if your div are generated dynamically, we cann't write the separate JAVAScript for every div for same functionality...

Comment: @NeelabhSingh - sorry, I don't understand your comment. The way I described, it works for **each** bucket div which is on page. Logic is encaptulated to each and every bucket container. I'll edit/update example a bit in a min.

Comment: @Kalle Volkov Thanks for Answer, Your code is working fine But When I click show more It hide the previous content. What I want, Suppose previously it will show the 4 list of items, but when I click show more It will show whole list, including previous, But you code hiding the previous..

Comment: Since you see the code, it's trivial to rearrange the div's to **not** hide some content. Just move `div class="intro"` outside `div class="mininfo"` div and you are done!

Comment: No, it *"cannot"* be reduced to a single line, if you want to have the proper `function() {` indentation

Comment: @NeelabhSingh - updated the example in JSFiddle to show which div to move and linked to it :)